# how to sort MySql query result based on Equality of results?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I want to search on Article Table. So I want to show results based on Equality of results.
when user search for "water", I want to show first results that Title Field exactly equals to "water" and then results that Title Field is like to "water" and then compare "water" with Description Field and so on.

I'm using Laravel 7 and php for my website.

[image]

Here user search for "بزوتنەوەى تاڵیبان".
In Query Result I want to show rows that title or description field exactly contain "بزوتنەوەى تاڵیبان", then rows that title or description fields like "بزوتنەوەى تاڵیبان".

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) Als show us your current query attempt. (I.e. [mcve].)

Comment: I added some details to my post.